# Create an SSH tunnel to legacy application's open socket connection

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a legacy application that I can't modify that accepts an open socket connection on port 8320 that is running on a linux device.

I would like to make it so that any clients trying to connect to the legacy app would have to make an ssh connection which would then tunnel the traffic to open socket connection created by the legacy application on port 8320.

I only want to make changes to the legacy linux device though. I couldn't find any examples that matched my scenario as most of the port forwarding examples involve forwarding traffic to another remote computer.

What configuration steps do I need to take?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the clients currently don't already open an ssh tunnel, then I suspect you'll have trouble changing them to use an ssh tunnel while only changing the legacy Linux device...
Do you just want the server to listen on a different port?

Comment: My software will be acting as the client, initializing the connection to the Linux devices. Currently all the traffic goes over the network as an open socket but I would like to make it only use ssh with a login and password. I basically want to patch an ssh connection to the device into an existing open socket server.

Comment: Will you be blocking remote access to port 8320?